# Cannot get access to ActiveProjects

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I would like to create a custom ribbon bar using VBA code. The examples that I have seen use the Application.ActiveProject property. In my Excel O365, ActiveProjects is not recognized. Am I missing a VBA reference?

Comment: What examples are you looking at? [`Application.ActiveProject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.activeproject) is from the Project API, not Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ActiveProjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa195547(v=office.11)) property belongs to Project, not Excel. The Fluent UI is described in-depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: That's where I am confused.  The code examples I'm finding for VBA use the ActiveProject.SetCustomUI method. How do a access the Project object?

Comment: The Excel object model doesn't provide such objects or methods.

Comment: Oh, MS Project only. Gotcha. Thank you.